# Rails 3, browser back functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, back, link-to

I am trying to get a back feature working on a Iphone web application.

I have looked at all the other posts about this issue, but none of them address my specific case.

This is my sequence of actions;

home page -> event page (click of a person name) -> person page

Right now, I have the <%= link_to 'Back', :back %> on both the event page and person page. 
With this kind of implementation, when I click on back from the person page, it takes me to the event page as expected. But when I click on back from the event page, it goes back to the person page because that is the page I came from.(whereas the expected functionality and the functionality from a browser back button would be to take me to the home page)..

Can anybody help me get this functionality in Rails?

Comment: Make sure you have JavaScript enabled. Could you please post the HTML code of your page. It should be something like: javascript:history.back()

Comment: Thanks Zepplock. When I changed <%= link_to "Back", :back %>  to <%= link_to "Back", 'javascript:history.back()' %> things worked fine. I didn't expect it to be this simple. The HTML for <%= link_to "Back", :back %> was not the one with javascript, it was the url itself. I have Javascript enabled in chrome. I'm not sure why this is the case though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the rails [documentation for the `link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) method you can read:

> (...) use :back to link to the
>   referrer - a JavaScript back link will
>   be used in place of a referrer if none
>   exists

And you can see that in the code of [`url_for` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/380800e4a272db98f3dd267f82e0ce1e4d03f4b8/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L100):

```
when :back
  controller.request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] || 'javascript:history.back()'
else
```

In your case, the referrer for the event page is the person page.
Like @Zepplock pointed, you probably want to hardcode the `javascript:history.back()`, [this is the same as clicking the Back button](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp).